# How to pass parameter to a function which expects a LPTSTR?

Tags: c++, windows

A function that expects an [LPTSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/windows-data-types-for-strings) `typedef LPWSTR PTSTR, LPTSTR;`

```
LPTSTR DriveGet(LPTSTR aValue)
{
}
```

How i could pass a value to it?

I tried calling the function all these ways:

```
auto List = DriveGet(_T("List");
auto List = DriveGet("List"); 
auto List = DriveGet(L"List");
```

In all i got compile errors about conversion `argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTSTR"`

Comment: All of the parameters you passed are `const`. Perhaps you should use `LPCTSTR`, or avoid the whole `TCHAR` nonsense and use `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`

Comment: @RetiredNinja changing their data type to `LPCTSTR` resulted in same compile error

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is that the full error message? With a function signature of `LPCTSTR DriveGet(LPCTSTR aValue)` the first option you showed will work with either Unicode or Multi-Byte projects. Consider putting together an actual [mcve] so we can see the full picture.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sorry, I forgot to also change the header, it still was using `LPTSTR`, now it compiled with `_T("List")`. Why do you say I should be using `LPCTSTR`? what's the difference between these two data types?

Comment: In C++ a string literal is const. In order to pass a string literal to a function the parameter must be const. That's what the `C` in `LPCTSTR` means. If you need a non-const string you'd have to do something like `TCHAR str[] = _T("List"); auto List = DriveGet(str);`